# XCode 5: How to make a reference file have a path relative to an environment variable

Tags: path, xcode5, environment-variables

Currently working on a **XCode 5** project, I was wondering how I could add a file to the project, using an environment variable for its path. For example, I'd like to link a java lib to my project, using `$JAVA_HOME` value. The value of JAVA_HOME will vary on every developer machine, depending on the used JDK.

I don't want to declare this variable in my source tree, because I'd like this configuration to work on any machine without having to declare this variable systematically.

My question should be close from [this one left unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19867156/how-do-i-get-xcode-5-to-see-global-environment-variables)

Is this possible?

Comment: Did you find an answer?

Comment: No, I haven't. I had to use a standard path for this type of files and hard-code it. You could use an alias, but there is no clean solution for this purpose.